# How to link an image to the header

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet where I am using an image in the header. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993154/can-i-use-vba-to-import-images-gifs-from-the-web-into-excel) I already know how to add or link images as **Shapes** in an Excel sheet.

Now I need to do something similar to the header, where I can link an Image to the header instead of saving the image in the Workbook (because I have a lot of images which makes the file size huge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code:

`Sheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename`

You need to set the `Filename` property of the `_____HeaderPicture` property to the path of the picture you want to use.

Comment: It works, but the problem is it stores the image inside the excel sheet once it is saved. I just need to **link** not to store the image inside the header.

Comment: You could always set it to link the image only when the file is open and then remove it before save...

Comment: Well the file is developed for non IT users which do heavy process on the sheet, so this option is very difficult to implement.

Comment: Actually I added a button that can remove the image from the Header once the user is finished printing. The events idea is good too. thanks mate :)

Comment: I don't even trust users to push buttons :-)